# Java String delete last letter in last value in JSON

Tags: javascript, java, json

So I have a little problem. When I use this code:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('output').innerHTML);
```

I get in console:

```
[
  {
    "type": "command",
    "command": {
      "type": "literal",
      "value": "echo"
    },
    "args": [
      {
        "type": "literal",
        "value": "test"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [],
    "env": {},
    "control": ";",
    "next": null
  }
]
```

So it's all ok. But when I pass it by form to java and later display this as string I'm getting:

```
[
  {
    "type": "command",
    "command": {
      "type": "literal",
      "value": "echo"
    },
    "args": [
      {
        "type": "literal",
        "value": "tes"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [],
    "env": {},
    "control": ";",
    "next": null
  }
]
```

It always deletes the last letter in last value. I'm passing it to Java in that way:

```
editor.session.on('change', function(e) {
   document.myform3.test.value = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
});
```

`<input type="hidden" name="test" value="">`

And I'm returning it in that way:

```
model.addObject("test", test);
```

And displaying in jsp page as `${test}`. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

@edit

My Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/kurs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView checkUserCode(String test) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("kurs");
    model.addObject("test", test);      
    return model;
}
```

@edit2
Full code of JavaScript version can be found here.
https://github.com/bmeck/js-shell-parse/tree/gh-pages
I'm just getting value of "output" and sending it to Java by HTML form.

Comment: There must be a length limitation somewhere in your code (however not in the posted part).

Comment: But for example when I do `echo "test"` I got deleted "t" in "test". But I can do `echo "test1" echo "test2" echo "test3" ... echo "test99" echo "pies"` so it will display every value of test from 1 to 99 ok, but last value ("pies") will be wrong, I will get only "pie". It always delete last letter in last value :/ So I don't think it's about length. And in console it's ok, but I got problem only in Java. I will edit my first post and put Java code here.

Comment: Strange, really need a more extensive code example though to see what all happens. Preferred also a fiddle so it can be simulated.